# Flutter connection refused when i try to make request to my nodejs api

Tags: flutter

I tried to call my api with flutter but when i make a request i have this error:

E/flutter (15338): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused

E/flutter (15338): #0 IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:88:7)

E/flutter (15338): 
E/flutter (15338): #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)

E/flutter (15338): 
E/flutter (15338): #2_withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:12)

E/flutter (15338): < asynchronous suspension>

Have you ever seen this error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I bet you are hosting the nodejs api locally at the moment? Also I bet youre testing on android? You are receiving this error because you cant directly connect to a localhost via android emulator/device. So you basically need to check which device is currently used. and change the localhost with your network port. for me its 192.168.178.23 for example.

put this in your code:

```
import 'dart:io';


String url = Platform.isAndroid ? 'http://192.168.178.23:3006' : 'http://localhost:3006';
```

and then you can change your request like this:

```
  final response =  await dio.get('${url}/api/myapi/myendpoint');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your node js server is running and check your url and domain name.

Change it with your machine IP. Run `ipconfig` command and get your IP gateway address.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
I just checked the server works well and when I make requests with postman everything works. Maybe I misconfigured the http package of flutter.

Comment: Have you resolved?

Comment: No :( I'll try to host my api to scalingo, maybe it's because i'm running all from my pc

Comment: What url you are using? When hosting in your PC

Comment: i was using localhost:3001